# Computer Algorithm that can I use for guessing word

Tags: android, ios

What computer algorithm can I use for creating a guessing word mobile game that compatible for the android and iOS platform?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links. This might help you.

1. [Optimal Algorithm for Winning Hangman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942861/optimal-algorithm-for-winning-hangman)
2. http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=301897
3. http://www.raywenderlich.com/33804/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-1